# How do I implement something like Digg Swarm in PHP or Python?

Tags: php, javascript, python, data-warehouse

http://labs.digg.com/swarm/

Comment: Which part of it? Specific questions allow us to actually offer specific advice.

Comment: I have the data. How do I make it visual?

Comment: Visual? Well for a start its built with Flash, you'll have a hard time implementing the visual aspect using PHP/Python and Javascript.

Comment: Anything in javascript that could be similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://raphaeljs.com/ For the Javascript data representation and i guess use PHP to talk with the API.